# Issue with CLLocationManager and CLLocationManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm running Xcode 10 and iOS 12

I'm getting this warning on each of the delegate methods coded in the class extension of my CLLocationManager singleton:

Instance method 'locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:)' of protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

public class PhysicalLocationManager: NSObject {

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //MARK: - Create Singleton Shared Instance
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    static let sharedInstance: PhysicalLocationManager = {
        let instance = PhysicalLocationManager()
        return instance
    }()

    let locationMgr: CLLocationManager

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //MARK: - Initialization
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    override init() {
        locationMgr = CLLocationManager()
        locationMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        super.init()
        locationMgr.delegate = self
    }

    func enableBasicLocationServices() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request when-in-use authorization initially
            locationMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break

        case .restricted, .denied:
            // Disable location features
            // TODO: disableMyLocationBasedFeatures()
            break

        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            // Enable location features
            enableWhenInUseFeatures()
            break
        }
    }

    func enableWhenInUseFeatures() {
        locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationMgr.requestLocation()
        }
    }

}

extension PhysicalLocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("\(manager)\tCLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization\n\(status)")

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("\(manager)\tCLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations\n\(locations)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    //  locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: 1. Please fix your code formatting. 2. Which version of Swift and Xcode are you using?

Comment: Fixed and added xCode 10 and iOS 12 to the question.  Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `PhysicalLocationManager` class is public, the delegate methods need to be public as well. Simply add `public` in front of the three delegate methods and the warnings go away.

Comment: That fix the initial question - Thanks!

Comment: Now I am it is executing the didFailWithError method but without the error populated  "error = Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: That would be for a new question. Be sure to post all relevant details.